# Does Blender generate audio?

Tags: audio

I've never entered any audio/sound into blender. I'm curious to know, does Blender generate sound for you? or is it all whatever I import?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/audio/speaker.html

Comment: No, blender is not an audio tool, you can import sounds and add them to the timeline. Think of blender as a 3D content and visual effects tool, the video editing and audio tools are quite basic.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate sound in blender while you load a sound into the speaker and place it in the 3d-Space. There you have than may an animation object and you can parent the speaker to it. Than you can render the sound and you have a 3d Sound.